# Set Adapter to linearLayout instead of listView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

I am working on a layout that needs to adapt to the kind of data I receive. I need to make this as generic as possible. So the layout in my adapter class needs to be modified dynamically according to the data. 
This is how I plan to do so.

My activity xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout id="1" ></LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout id="2" ></LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout id="3" ></LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout id="4" ></LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout id="5" ></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have adapter which populates data. Adapter code
  1. Inflate new layout N1
  2. Get id of activity `LinearLayout` based on adapter item position
  3. Put N1 in parent `LinearLayout` Slot

Problem. How do I use Static `LinearLayout` than `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
LinearLayout holder = new LinearLayout(context);
...
holder.removeAllViews();
for(int i = 0 ; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) 
    holder.addView(adapter.getView(i, null, holder));
...
```

Comment: The issue was fixed. We were using ViewHolder pattern before. That cause the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ListView and just supply a custom layout to the rows

Comment: I was using viewHolder to optimize the app. Guess there is no other choice.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you should be able to use a SimpleAdapter and a list view to handle what you need. Is there any specific reason you need to use a linear layout as the parent view?

"An adapter manages the data model and adapts it to the individual entries in the widget. An adapter extends the BaseAdapter class.

Every line in the widget displaying the data consists of a layout which can be as complex as you want. A typical line in a list has an image on the left side and two text lines in the middle as depicted in the following graphic."

[image: example]

This information and more can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: Thank you. Was able to fix the issue

Comment: If this helped you solve your issue could you please select this as an answer so that it may help others in the future.